# Justifying implicit limits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, tangent-line

Consider the hyperbola given as:
$$\frac{x^2}{4}- \frac{y^2}{12} =1$$

Divide through by $x^2$

$$ \frac14 - \frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2= \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Now, here is the tricky step, I take limit as $ x \to \infty$ on both sides, this kills the RHS, and doing some algebra in the back, I get:

$$ 3= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2$$

Now, I want to say that the slope of tangent line infinity/ asymptote to parabola has slope of $\sqrt{3}$ i.e: $ \lim_{x \to \infty} y' = 3$ and say that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(y'\right)^2 = \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2$ is that possible?

I considered using [Stolz Casero theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro,it%20for%20the%20first%20time.) for this, but for it I'd need a sequence, now how do I get a sequence such that I can say the above equivalence?

Comment: If you're trying to find the limit behavior of the derivative, why not differentiate before taking the limit? Otherwise you'll have trouble ruling out cases like $y=x+\sin x$, where $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac yx=1$ but $\frac{dy}{dx}$ does not converge.

Comment: You need to do a lot more to ensure $y'$ don't e.g. oscillate wildly like $y=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sin(x^{20})$ while keeping $y/x$ under control.

Comment: On the other hand one can show (by "zooming out") that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists, then it equals $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac yx$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'zooming out'? @Karl

Comment: I'd prove it using the definition of a limit, but the intuition is that if the slope of $f$ converges to a fixed value $m$, then if you zoom out far enough on the graph, it'll just look like the line $y=mx$.

Comment: Actually, this is just L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{y^2}{x^2}=3$ is a result you derived from the original equation. It contains relationship between x and y. We know that x is a set of constant values in R. In order for the equation to be true, y has to be the same order with x.
For example, if $y=x^2$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{y^2}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^4}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x^2=\infty$.
So it actually depends on your definition for y. If you use $y=f(x)=ax, a\in R$, you can solve the limit directly.\

If a function is continuous on $R$, for any point in it's co-domain, there must exist a sequence convergent to it. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, there must exist a sequence convergent to it.

Comment: So, you are saying to use that continuity implies sequence and use that to apply stolz casero? What about if it is like an oscillating limit as @user10354138 in comment of original post?

Comment: If the sequence is oscillating, it is needed to find a sequence which satisfies epsilon–delta definition of limit.